# fetch и XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest, fetch

Пытаюсь отправить запрос на сервер и получить ответ, но не получается сделать это всё сразу.

С помощью fetch почему-то не передаются параметры:

```
    let formData = {
        name: "Пушкин А.С.",
        age: "221"
    };

const response = fetch('server.php',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify('name=' + encodeURIComponent(formData.name) + '&age=' + encodeURIComponent(age.weight))
    })
```

А вот XMLHttpRequest передаёт всё верно, в консоли Network я вижу ответ, но вывести его не получается, выдаёт пустую строку в случае с `console.log(request.response)` и ошибку с `console.log(JSON.parse(request.response))`

```
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open('POST', 'server.php', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    request.send('name=' + encodeURIComponent(formData.name) + '&age=' + encodeURIComponent(formData.age));
    console.log(JSON.parse(request.response))
```

Comment: Ну так в XMLHttpRequest вы не используете json, а с fetch зачем-то используете

Comment: @andreymal гениально! :D убрал JSON.stringify и заработало, спасибо!